# Is there any difference between #pragma unroll(0) and #pragma unroll(1)?

Tags: c, pragma, icc, unroll

I read the document about the loop unrolling.
It explains that if you set unrolling factor as 1, then the program will work like with #pragma nounrolling.

However, that documents does not include #pragma unroll(0) case..
Since the range of n is 0 to 255, I'm just wondering out of curiosity there is any difference between #pragma unroll(0) and #pragma unroll(1) cases.

I'm using C with icc compiler.

Comment: I suspect it would be equivalent, though you're right, they don't mention it. However [they do mention](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524556): `If n is omitted or if it is outside the allowed range, the optimizer assigns the number of times to unroll the loop.` I'd imagine it's outside of that range.

Comment: Thank you very much!
To figure out the differences, I've tested for 10^6 times of adding array elements. However, I can not find any performance difference not only between unroll(0) and unroll(1) but also between unroll, unroll(0), unroll(1), ... , unroll(8).
Could you suggest more suitable experiments to capture the different features?

Comment: I believe these directives are only active with the additional "O3" optimization in the compile args

Comment: Yes, I've tested with -O3 compiler option..

Answer (score 1):

From the Intel documentation:

> The compiler generates correct code by comparing n and the loop count.

Based on that, I would make an assumption there is no difference between `#pragma unroll(0) and #pragma unroll(1)` as the the code generated would be equivalent.